# Ошибка связанная с Message.delete() в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Идея кода: при "/start" бота выводится сообщение с инлайн кнопкой, при нажатии, то же сообщение удаляется

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, Message

bot = Bot(token='Токен бота')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Любой текст', callback_data='button1')

func = lambda c: c.data == 'button1'
@dp.callback_query_handler(func)
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await Message.delete(dlt_msg)

@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
async def start(message : types.Message):
    global dlt_msg
    dlt_msg = message.reply('Любой текст', reply_markup=inline_kb1)
    await dlt_msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Ошибка, возникающая при попытке нажать на кнопку:

```
'coroutine' object has no attribute 'bot'
```

И сразу два вопроса:

1. Откуда взялся объект `coroutine`?
2. И почему у него должен быть атрибут `bot`?

Если мыслей на счёт первого нет вообще, то вот на счёт второго я пошёл в саму библиотеку aiogram и смотреть что там, да как...
И обнаружил вот такой код в классе `message`:

```
async def delete(self) -> base.Boolean:
    
    return await self.bot.delete_message(self.chat.id, self.message_id)
```

Ииииииии ничего не понял, во-первых почему тот объект, который мы посылаем в метод должен стоять выше по иерархии `bot`'а? Ведь я хочу удалить сообщение, а оно является частью `message`, а он частью `types`, а он уже как раз наравне с `bot`, разве нет? Во-вторых, по аналогии непонятки с агрументами внутри `delete_message`

(P.S. в классе `chat` есть метод `delete_message` чем он отличается от `delete_message` в классе `bot`? И в чем разница их обоих от `delete` в классе `message`?)

Comment: Я почитал про coroutine, я правильно понимаю, что python так (либо async) называет внутри себя любой объект связанный с асинхронностью?

Comment: Попробуйте `await Message.delete(await dlt_msg)`

Comment: а более классический подход чем плох? вы буд-то велосипед второй раз делаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что надо не

```
await Message.delete(dlt_msg)
```

А вот так

```
await callback_query.message.delete()
```

А вообще, то что вы сделали какой-то ужас. Вы можете убрать кучу лишнего кода.

```
# пожалуйста забудьте про лямбда функции, используйте их реже, в большинстве случаев можно сделать так, текст это фильтр для той самой колбек даты, а в случае месседж хендлера - для текста сообщения
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="button1")
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    # я думаю это более лаконичный способ
    await callback_querry.answer()
    # в callback_query.message сейчас то сообщение инлайн клавиатура которого была нажата, поэтому никикие глобальные переменные нам не нужны
    await callback_query.message.delete()

@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
async def start(message : types.Message):
    await message.reply('Любой текст', reply_markup=inline_kb1)
```

Comment: Хорошее решение) Даже познавательное.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло...можете ли пожалуйста объяснить чем плохи лямбда функции?
На счёт ужаса, да, я понимал, что сделал костыль, но 3 строчки кода, как мне кажется, не куча...
Во-вторых, если бы я изначально знал о стольких вариантах удаления, и, конкретно ваш, то явно использовал его. В P.S. об этом намекается, когда я узнал о существовании тех или иных функций, но не понял их применения.К чему я веду, если мне понадобится когда-либо использовать именно Message.delete(), то как его использовать?И остальные вопросы, которые остались без ответа, например "Почему у него должен быть атрибут bot?"

Comment: Лямбда функции не плохи, просто они читаются хуже чем просто текст=... Насчёт почему нужен атрибут бот, ну смотрите вы обращаетесь к классу месседж и вызываете метод удаления, однако сам класс месседж не знает какой экземпляр бота ему использовать, в моем случае мы обратились не к классу а к скорее экземпляру класса и вот он знает о том какой бот ему использовать. Примерно так

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
#Создаем собственно кнопку для удаление сообщения
btn_send_delete = InlineKeyboardButton('Удалить', callback_data='message_delete')
btn_send_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(btn_send_delete)

#Реагируем на команду /start, при этом выводим сообщение с инлайн кнопкой
@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def del_mes(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'test', reply_markup=btn_send_markup)

#Если нажимаем на кнопку - удаляется сообщение.
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'message_delete')
async def send_msg_to_user(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.answer('Удалено')
    await bot.delete_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
```