# Удаление цитируемого сообщения командой Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['del'], commands_prefix="!")
async def delete(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply('Эта команда должна быть ответом на сообщение!')
    else:
        await message.delete(message.reply_to_message.message_id)
```

имеется такой код, но выводится ошибка:

```
TypeError: Message.delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Хз твоя функция принимает только 1 аргумент, ты же дал 2

Comment: Если `message.reply_to_message` это объект Message, и именно это сообщение нужно удалить, то и метод delete нужно вызывать от этого объекта: `message.reply_to_message.delete()`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1383237/Ошибка-связанная-с-message-delete-в-aiogram.    Похожий вопрос уже есть.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что message.delete не требует аргументов. У него есть свой `self` ,то бишь объект `Message` у которого вы вызываете метод `delete`.
Но я так догадываюсь что вы сообщение цитируете и пишите команду, и после хотите чтобы цитируемое сообщение удалялось.
Думаю где-то вот так.

```
async def delete(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply('Эта команда должна быть ответом на сообщение!')
    else:
        # либо так
        await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.message_id)
        # либо так
        await message.reply_to_message.delete()
```